# How can I use bigints package and yhmath package together?

Tags: amsmath, delimiters, yhmath

I want to make `wide parentheses` and symboles like them.  I used  `yhmath` package in my file and It worked correctly. 
But when I use the `bigints` package in my file too everything will break down.
I mean the size of my integrals is not `big`.
Who smells rat?
I studied `yhmath` package and saw this command:
`\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{yhex}{m}{n}`
This command has its side effect on the `bigints` package and `delimiters` which are in the `ams` package too.
How can I use both of
(`bigints&yhmath` package) together
and where can I study about commands like below?
`\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{yhex}{m}{n}`
`\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{txr}{m}{n}`
`\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{OT1}{txr}{bx}{n}`
Thanks for your responsibility.
This is my example file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage{bigints}
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}
\[\wideparen{abcggg}\quad \widetriangle{abc}\quad\widering{abc}\]
\[\bigintsss_0^5{x^3}\diff{x}\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `yhmath` package loads the math extension font at a fixed size. You can make it scalable. However, I'm recommending not to use `bigint`: variable size integrals are not really nice.

I've also redefined `\widering` as the default definition is disputable.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage{bigints}

\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{yhex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{yhex}{m}{n}{<-> yhcmex10 }{}

\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\renewcommand{\widering}[1]{\mathring{\wideparen{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\[\wideparen{abcggg}\quad \widetriangle{abc}\quad\widering{abc}\]
\[\bigintsss_0^5{x^3}\diff{x}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]